# how to insert tab spaces when snipmate is installed

Tags: vim, snipmate

I want to insert tab spaces in insert mode but snipmate wouldnt allow me to  do so.
How do i either re-map snipmate trigger button to something other than tab or is there any other way to insert tab spaces when snipmate is installed.

Thanks

Comment: Snipmate's expansion is triggered on `<Tab>` *when the cursor is after an identified trigger*: it shouldn't prevent you from inserting actual tabs when that condition is not met.

Comment: Even i thought so, but for some reason snipmate is not working as expected.

Comment: Check if you have the SuperTab plugin installed. I experienced your problem and it was SuperTab that was giving me grief. I uninstalled it and all is well.

Comment: The guy who downvoted this must be a complete moron, I have the same problem, maybe someone thinks that our problems shouldn't get solved or something? +1 to the question and I guess `supertab` is my problem as well since I have it installed :S

Answer (score 0):

no matter what plugin you installed, this should work anyway (INSERT mode):

```
c-v<tab>
```

Comment: I just read your question `is there any other way to insert tab spaces when snipmate is installed.` . :)

Comment: sorry about that, i think my question was worded wrong. I want to be able to insert tab spaces with the tab key while also having snipmate installed..:)

Comment: I found that this happens only when snipmate is run along with supertab.